# How to call several addOnLoad functions in dojo?

Tags: django, dojo

I'm trying to define several dojo elements from several (inherited) HTML pages , and each defines addOnLoad of his own, which causes only the latest function to be executed, since they are overridden.
Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use blocks to replace inherited elements

in template-base:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
  {% block extra-header %} 
    #code default
    ...
  {% endblock %}
</head>
```

in template:

```
{% block extra-header %} 
{{ block.super }}
   #replacement code
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
{% endblock %}
```

for more information see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: I want both the default and the new code to be executed. If I replace the old block with the new one, I lose the old function.

Comment: add {{ block.super }} inside the block. 
already edit it in the example